# Windows forms, form's icon issue

Tags: c#, .net, windows-7-x64

I have next problem: I want to change the icon of the WindowsForm application in runtime. I use next code for it:

```
this.Icon = DealerOnlineCheckerWF.Properties.Resources.DO_green;
```

And this code work fine when I compile it in VisualStudio. But after deploying the app via Visual Studio Setup project(even on the same machine) the icon that appear on taskbar is not changable. What can be the reason of that ?

**I've just debug the deployed app and was surprised that CLR just jump over the line(without executing) where I try to change the icon. What is that ?**

Comment: are you sure, you are trying to change the application icon ? not the icon that you can see in windows explorer ?

Comment: Make sure your `Resources` copied while complile setup project.

Comment: @RohitPrakash I mean the next one http://joxi.ru/krDxdYxfz9egrp .

Comment: @AnantDabhi I'm sure that rosources are included in the executable, because I change in the same way the icon of notififyIcon control.

Comment: "Just jump over the line" is a strong sign of using try/catch and swallowing the exception.  Don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

The icon should change so if it is not changing after deploying it maybe is because there is an exception. Another option can be that you are not deploying the same binaries that you tested and the deployed code does not contain something required.

In any case I recommend you to attach to the deployed machine with the remote debugger and check what is happening.

[Remote Debug](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7f5zaaa(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: I've just debug the deployed app and was surprised that CLR just jump over the line(without executing) where I try to change the icon. What is that ?

Comment: That the debugged binary does not have this line. Try to put a breakpoint and you will probably see a message saying that the source code does not match the binary.

Comment: I don't know what's going on but I've get next issue: when I deploy this application with VS Installer than the icon is unchangable, but when I copy the files that was deployed via this installer into another directory (it can be even an inner handmaded directory in insalled folder) the icon change like a charm. Terrible installer. What can be the reason of the issue ?